# Ajax request with empty form field to Spring controller

Tags: ajax, spring, forms, spring-mvc

This is web project I tray to send data from the form to server ( Spring part).  I send  multipart request to server with  Ajax. Problem arise if user left empty form fields. if all form input complete  request work fine. I find some posts but this not my case and not worked with multipart request. In project I don’t use anotetion like @Valid @NotNull for to check validity on server side.  Spring not show error, only Firebug  show network error 400 bad request. What is going wrong in code. What is best way to check validity  the empty form field for multipart request.

Ajax code

```
function casePostUpload()
    {
var myForm = form.find('formAddPoster');
    myData = new FormData();
    myData.append('multipart',  myForm);


enter code her$
          .ajax({

              url : "/video/addCasePost",
              //url: urlFromActionFild,
              data : myForm,
             // data : myData,
              type : 'POST',
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              processData: false, 
              contentType:false,
              success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){


                  $('#casePost').prepend('<br/>Poster: '+data.casePoster+' ::  title '+data.caseTitle+' at '+data.timestampAsStr+'<br/></td></tr>');


            },
              error : function(result){
                  //...;

                alert('add contnt error: ' + errorThrown);
              }
          });
    }
```

Spring MVC controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/video/addCasePost",   method = RequestMethod.POST )
 public @ResponseBody CasePost addcasepost( @RequestPart("caseTitle") String caseTitleString, 
    @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @ModelAttribute("currentuser") User currentuser) throws Exception {
   CasePost jsResponse = new CasePost();



            }catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e);
            }

    }   

    try {
        if (caseTitleString != null) {
            jsResponse.setCaseTitle(caseTitleString); 
            jsResponse.setCasePoster(filePath);
jsResponse = graphStoryInterface.getCasePostInterface().add(jsResponse, currentuser);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }

 return jsResponse;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default params are required by Spring unless you specify otherwise. Set @RequestPart(required = false, value="aFieldName")

Comment: If you want to accept the answer you need to accept it yourself:)

Comment: Im tray but the low level reputation prevent it. Thanks for answer.